# Games services are not published

Tags: google-play-services, publish

I am trying to publish an ALPHA version of my Game. But, I got this message "Games Services are not published". I couldn't find where exactly I can publish "Games Services" nor how.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The warning in the Google Docs about publishing the APK before the Game Services is **ONLY** applicable if you want to publish a **RELEASE** version. If you publish Game Services then you **CAN NO LONGER** delete your Game.
If you want to publish an Alpha/Beta versions, **DO NOT** publish Game Services!!!

**DO NOT DO THIS FOR ALHPHA OR BETA!**
**DO IT ONLY FOR PRODUCTION VERSION!!!**
https://play.google.com/apps/publish/
In the tab on the left: Game Services->Publishing->Publish Your Game
(Sorry for the caps, but I made a irreversible mistake, so warning others)

Comment: So to test in BETA you only need the GPS to be "ready to test" and of course require a new APK to be in BETA. Do you know if the APK needs to be published?